# Is there a way to see changelog of update?

Tags: updates, appcenter

Title says it all. Is this a thing? A changelog for every update in AppCenter (obviously just for elementary apps) would be really helpful.

Comment: Same issue here. If i click on the updated program i can only see the ordinary AppCenter window with the screenshot etc. in case of os updates AppCenter keeps loading and loading without showing any changelog or anything else...

Comment: I third this. I simply cannot continue to run any system where I cannot see what packages and system components are updated, upgraded, or otherwise changed. There is no such thing as security through obscurity. Please give us a changelog!

Answer (score 3):

There currently is not, but there is already a [filed feature request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/appcenter/+bug/1612810). At the moment, packages don't provide changelogs, so this would require both adding support in AppCenter for showing appstream release tag data and for apps to implement it