# Interim way to view changelog when OS updates are available?

Tags: release-loki, updates, appcenter

I am aware of [the request and bounty for viewing the changelog associated with an OS update in the App Center](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7848/is-there-a-way-to-see-changelog-of-update).  In the meantime, is there anywhere else we can find the changelog?  Perhaps somewhere on Launchpad (most likely would be Announcements on [the main launchpad page for elementary](https://launchpad.net/elementary), but not all updates have an accompanying announcement)?  I just want to know whether any given update includes a fix for one of the bugs I've been experiencing, or is a security patch, or is cosmetic in nature, etc.

I am running Loki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Launchpad projects do include changelogs, they are created with the `.deb` packaging and have no substantive detail. For example, see logs for [`pantheon-files`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-os/pantheon-files/deb-packaging/view/head:/debian/changelog) or [`wingpanel-indicator-sound`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-os/wingpanel-indicator-sound/deb-packaging/view/head:/debian/changelog), which also viewable once downloaded at `/usr/share/docs/` in folders by package name. Launchpad [doesn't support](https://bugs.launchpad.net/appcenter/+bug/1612810/comments/2) changelogs for PPAs. So unless elementary devs go out of their way to manually create specific notes alongside new releases, there is no summarized accounting for the changed code, nevertheless something accessible. For non-elementary packages that do contain news files/changelogs, you can [install `apt-listchanges`](http://jxf.me/entries/better-apt-ubuntu/).

If you are following bugs in a specific elementary app, you can go to its Launchpad page > "Bugs" tab, sort by "Status" descending, which will list the most recent "fixes committed" at the top. And if you are following individual bugs, there is an option in the sidebar of each bug's page to receive notifications only when the issue is closed, if that would help.

[image: Add a mail subscription]

Comment: So there is really no way to know what is happening when we install updates for the OS in AppCenter.  As much as I love elementary OS, this is crazy.  I mean I guess the devs realize this because the bounty is there but I thought that in the meantime there must be a simple page with release notes *somewhere* if not on Launchpad.  I just can't imagine releasing software updates without telling my users what the update is.

Comment: I agree, and I imagine that's why the job has a bounty. I also imagine it's connected to the team's backseat plans of switching bug tracking platforms, which will change the release process